# How can I pull off the circular reveal ripple transition used in all the Material Design videos?

Tags: android, animation, android-transitions

This video here perfectly explains the effect I am trying to replicate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/red7n.jpg

I am able to create a circular reveal as instructed in the documentation but I have no idea how to combine it with that color ripple.

Is there any suggestion on how to do this properly?